# How to describe students who don't study hard

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to describe a situation here:

> The students who study hard usually get better grade, but in contrast the students who didn't study hard usually get poor grade.

However, I don't want to use "the students who didn't study hard" to depict the other students.(Because lots of vocabularies repeat again.)

Any alternatives?

Comment: You could also characterize the two groups as _the interested_ and _the bored_. Whatever terms you choose, they'll be wrong because no one motive, intention, or characteristic accounts for good and bad grades in school.

Comment: *Students who study hard get good grades; those that don't, don't.*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Requests for writing advice or criticism are on topic at Writers.SE. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use *lackadaisical* in the sense of not really paying attention or caring:

From Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> lackadaisical, adj.
>
> full of vapid feeling or sentiment; affectedly languishing. Said of persons, their behaviour, manners, and utterances.

In use:

> The students who study hard usually get better grades, but in contrast the *lackadaisical* students usually get poor grades.

Or you could try *laggard* in the sense of *lagging behind* from OED:

> laggard, adj. and n.
>
> Lagging, hanging back, loitering, slow. Chiefly of living things, their actions, and attributes.
>
> One who lags behind; a lingerer, loiterer.

In use:

> The students who study hard usually get better grades, but in contrast the *laggards* usually get poor grades.

Comment: [Sluggard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sluggard) is my favorite.

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking for something a little more colloquial, *[slacker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slacking)* is used to describe a person who is lazy or doesn't perform his duties. The UK equivalent is *skiving*.

When used as a verb, "off" is often included, as in

> but in contrast the students who slack off get poor grades.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about _skive_ here; that would carry the connotation that the student didn't study at all; to _skive off games_ means not to do games at all, not to do them lazily or unenthusiastically. See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skive) (meaning 2).

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that "students who slack off" is gentler than "slackers" because it implies a temporary situation rather than a personality characteristic.

Answer (score 8):

You can call the two groups *diligent* and *negligent* respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider *studious* and *inattentive* for the two groups respectively.

Comment: I find it hard to agree with *inattentive* just because being inattentive doesn't necessarily mean that you will get bad grades. We need a word which could clearly depict the act of *not studying hard*.

Answer (score 2):

If the aim is simply to avoid repeating all those words (*students*, *study* and *hard*), you can simply use words like *others* or *the rest* as well as elision (direct omission of words that are understood from context, within the limits allowed by the language):

Some possible endings:

*The students who study hard usually get better grades, whereas ...*

- *the rest do not.*
- *the others do not.*
- *those who don't, don't.*

In the last one, it is understood that the first *don't* refers to *don't study hard* and the second *don't* refers to *don't get better grades* due to the expected order of the clauses.

Comment: I really think that in the context of OP who seems to be a foreign speaker, this is the best kind of answer. "Those who don't" provides a good reusable construction, instead of a fancy vocabulary word with limited capacity for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Students who are not taking the educational opportunity seriously are "uncommitted" and certain to join the unemployed in their chosen profession.

Comment: I agree that such students are "uncommitted", but I doubt that they have "a chosen profession" other than being supported by mom and dad. I was a total slacker in secondary school and had no chosen profession until I hit my mid-20s. But that choice didn't stick with me, nor did I stick with it. That didn't happen till I was in my mid-50s.